# Animated shadow in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, shadow, cabasicanimation

My app shows an animation of rotating fan blades in front of the fan body and background.  The image of the blades is a PNG with transparency residing in a UIImageView and I have no problem applying a drop shadow to it, or making that view rotate nicely.  But my problem is that the drop shadow also rotates with the image, as if the light source was also rotating.

The code below works fine to create a drop shadow and to rotate the image, but the shadow rotates along with blades and of course that doesn't look realistic.  How can I make the light source hold still and recalculate the shadow for each frame of animation?

```
    func startRotating(_ duration: Double = 2) {
    let kAnimationKey = "rotation"
    if self.layer.animation(forKey: kAnimationKey) == nil {
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 2
        let animate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        animate.duration = duration
        animate.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        animate.fromValue = 0.0
        animate.toValue = Float(.pi * 2.0)
        self.layer.add(animate, forKey: kAnimationKey)
    }
}
```

Response to first two comments:

[image: Fan]

The problem both comments miss is that the shadow cast by a fan blade varies depending on the position of the blade in its rotation, but the apparent position of the light source should not.  Imagine a typical drop shadow down and to the right of a horizontal fan blade, say at 45°.  It's a 4-blade fan so there is a similar shadow on both sides.  With the code shown, once the blades have rotated 180° and look identical to the starting position, both drop shadows are now above and to the left of the fan blades (see screen shot), making it look as if the light source has also rotated along with the blades.  It's no different than a having a single image of the blades that includes a static drop shadow, and them rotating that image.  In fact that's exactly what is happening, the shadow is only calculated once before rotation begins.  I need the shadow to be recast for each frame on the fly.

Comment: I don't fully imagine the result. Attaching an example image would be helpful. However, the easiest way to disconnect shadow from the layer would be to create another layer, of similar shape, apply shadow to it and translate it so that the result looks realistic.

Comment: @MishaKarpenko is correct. Create a second image that is just the drop shadow offset it from the original image according to where you want the shadow to be relative to the original image and rotate them Both.

Comment: I've added more detail to the original question in response to these comments.

Comment: I'm getting the sense that I need to use OpenGL to accomplish what I want.  Something like this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caeagllayer     But I've never done any animation so this is very daunting.